# Nested aggregation in nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am new to elasticsearch and don't know a lot about aggregations but I have this ES6 mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
                "countries": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "global_id": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "areas": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "global_id": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "parent_global_id": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get all documents grouped by `areas` which is then grouped by `countries`. Also the document has to be returned in full, not just the nested document. Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Aggregation _search query:

first agg by area, with the path as this is nested. Then reverse to the root document and nested agg to country.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_areas": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "areas"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "areas_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "areas.name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_reverse": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "agg_countries": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "countries"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "countries_name": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "countries.name"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2) retrieve documents:

add a tophits inside your aggregation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

top_hits is slow so you will have to read documentation and adjust size and sort to your context.

```
...
"terms": {
            "field": "areas.name"
          },
    "aggregations": {
                    "hits": {
                        "top_hits": { "size": 100}
                    }
                },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try that out. But doesn't `top_hits` only return the child doc ?

Comment: Yes it is. If you add top_hits in the both level you will have full data. But maybe you need the id value too? Can you describe what you need to do with these data? maybe an inner_hits query could resolve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by both level ? Could you may be show me an example ? I tried putting top_hits as sub aggregation for `countries_name` but it gives me this error `Child query must not match same docs with parent filter. Combine them as must clauses (+) to find a problem doc.`